# Memory exhausted sending mails with pdf file attached (swiftmailer set to file)

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I am trying to send emails with pdf attached.
I have a Command to send a lot of emails and swiftmailer is configured in file spool but I have this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in .....vendor/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 4989
```

My swiftmailer configuration is:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: file,  path: "%kernel.root_dir%/spool" }
```

and my Command is:

```
class EnviarJustificanteCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand {
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('preinscripciones:enviar')
            ->setDescription('Enviar Justificantes')
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {   
        $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
        $textoMailPreinscripcion = "......";
        //find alumnos
        $preinscritos = $em->getRepository('BackendAlumnosBundle:Historial')->findAlumnosEnviarJustificante();
        foreach ($preinscritos as $key => $alumno) {

            if ($alumno->getEmail() != null) {
                $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                    ->setSubject('Preinscripción realizada')
                    ->setFrom(array($this->container->getParameter('fromemail.contact') => '........'))
                    ->setReplyTo($this->container->getParameter('replyto.email'))
                    ->setTo($alumno->getEmail())
                    ->setBody($textoMailPreinscripcion);

                // Create your file contents in the normal way, but don't write them to disk
                $data = $this->imprmirJustificantePreinscripcionPDF($escuela, $alumno, true);
                // Create the attachment with your data
                $attachment = \Swift_Attachment::newInstance($data, 'JustificantePreinscripcion.pdf', 'application/pdf');
                // Attach it to the message
                $message->attach($attachment);
                $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

            }
            //set flag to 0 as sent
            foreach ($alumno->getHistorial() as $key => $historial) {
                $historial->setEnviarJustificante(false);
                $em->persist($alumno);
            }
        }

        $em->flush(); 
    }
}
```

I don't know why I have configured swiftmailer as type file the memory is exhausted. Some clue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

`Swift_Attachment::newInstance()` accepts data either as a String or a Stream that implements `Swift_OutputByteStream`.

You are using a String, which in your case is too big for memory. (Swift performs a base64 encode, which chews up even more memory)

You need to pass your data as a Stream, which enables incremental reads.

In your case you could do this by writing the data to disk, then getting a file resource handle, and wrapping that in an wrapper class.

An example for your Wrapper class is:

```
class AttachmentStream implements Swift_OutputByteStream
{
    protected $resource;

    public function __construct($resource)
    {
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }

    public function read($length)
    {
        $string = fread($this->resource, $length);

        if(false === $string){
            throw new Swift_IoException('Unable to read from stream');
        }

        return (0 === strlen($string)) ? false : $string;
    }

    public function setReadPointer($byteOffset)
    {
        return 0 === fseek($this->resource,$byteOffset);
    }
}
```

You could then call it like:

```
...
$fp          = fopen($file,$mode);
$stream      = new AttachmentStream($fp);
$filename    = 'JustificantePreinscripcion.pdf';
$contentType = 'application/pdf';
$attach      = Swift_Attachment::newInstance($stream,$filename,$contentType);
```

Comment: Awesome- i was looking at the default classes implementing Swift_OutputByteStream and was wondering why there wasnt a simple class like this that just wraps an existing resource. Thanks !

Answer (score -2):

Looks like it's dying in TCPD while trying to generate a PDF file.  Not too surprising; TCPDF is pretty crufty.  Give the http://knpbundles.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle bundle a try, it uses wkhtmltopdf (http://wkhtmltopdf.org/).  Should be considerably faster and is unlikely to bump up against memory restrictions.

Comment: I appreciate your comments but I am using swiftmailer for over my application, and now I can't change for another bundle.

Comment: Is TCPDF bundled with Swiftmailer?  I think maybe not.. at least not with the latest version (I'm using 5.2.0).  In the above it looks like "$this->imprmirJustificantePreinscripcionPDF($escuela, $alumno, true)" is generating the PDF in memory via TCPDF and then returning the PDF binary as a variable.  I think if you were to replace this call with something that used another library your problem would go away. Alternatively generating the PDF to a tmp file rather than in memory might work.